# How to create responsive Breadcrumbs in materializecss?

Tags: html, css, jsp, materialize

[image: small or mobile screen breadcrumb][image: Full screen breadcrumb]I am using materializecss for front end In my jsp pages, I am using Breadcrumbs  for show  information on top of the page it's working fine but whenever I seen my pages on mobile browser or small screen then whole Breadcrumbs is not showing. So how to make responsice any suggestion ?

```
<div class="section" style="padding-bottom:0;">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="breadcrumb-nav col l12 truncate" style="height:40px; line-height: 40px;">
                    <a class="breadcrumb" href="<c:url value="/"/>">Home</a>
                    <a class="breadcrumb" href="<c:url value="/${currentCityName}"/>">${currentCity.name}</a>
                    <c:forEach items="${breadCategories}" var="c">
                        <c:set var="puri"><catalog:CategoryUri category="${c}"/></c:set>
                        <a class="breadcrumb" href="<c:url value="/${currentCityName}${puri}"/>">${c.name}</a>
                    </c:forEach>                
                    <a class="breadcrumb" href="javascript:;">${product.name}</a>
                </nav>                   
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you embed your code on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, for the mobile device you can ignore the breadcrumb part as it doesn't looks nice on a mobile screen. Hence, it would be a waste of space.

e.g.:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
   .breadcrumb-nav {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

Or you can also decrease the font size of your breadcrumb:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
   .breadcrumb-nav {
      font-size:;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but it might work if you replace

`<nav class="breadcrumb-nav col l12 truncate" style="height:40px; line-height: 40px;">`

with

`<nav class="breadcrumb-nav col s12 truncate" style="height:40px; line-height: 40px;">`

The difference is l12 becomes s12. this tells materialize to give the breadcrumbs 12 columns on small and higher.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing from `l12 to s12`, you have another issue.

The reason your breadcrumbs are being cut off is due to the `truncate` class. By design, Materialize will cut off any content that exceeds the size of the container/screen. [Materialize Documentation on Helpers](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html)

Try removing this class. Then you may have other styling issues, but it shouldn't be cut off any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Your breadcrumb is going out in the mobile screen so you need to check your mobile css and try this one this might help you

```
<nav class="breadcrumb-nav col l12 truncate" style="height:40px; line-height: 40px;">
```

TO

```
<nav class="breadcrumb-nav col s12 truncate" style="height:40px; line-height: 40px;">
```

here is the [reference](http://materializecss.com/breadcrumbs.html) that might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this code here is example

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="col s12">
        <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">First</a>
        <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Second</a>
        <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Third</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add style `word-wrap: break-word` in the text, and i think it will work just fine